# How to start more than 16 Android emulators

Tags: android, android-emulator, adb

With 16 emulators running, `adb devices` shows

```
List of devices attached
emulator-5584
emulator-5582
emulator-5580
emulator-5578
emulator-5576
emulator-5574
emulator-5572
emulator-5570
emulator-5568
emulator-5566
emulator-5564
emulator-5562
emulator-5560
emulator-5558
emulator-5556
emulator-5554
```

To start the 17th emulator, I run:

```
emulator -avd Nexus_4_API_19_17 -ports 5586,5587
```

but I later get the following warning

> emulator: WARNING: Requested adb port (5587) is outside the recommended range [5555,5586]. ADB may not function properly for the emulator. See -help-port for details.

And `adb devices` doesn't show new emulators. Running `emulator -help-port` doesn't provide any useful information:

> At startup, the emulator tries to bind its control console at a free
>   port starting from 5554, in increments of two (i.e. 5554, then 5556,
>   5558, etc..)  this allows several emulator instances to run
>   concurrently on the same  machine, each one using a different console
>   port number.  use '-port ' to force an emulator instance to use
>   a given console port  note that  must be an *even* integer
>   between 5554 and 5584 included.  +1 must also be free and will
>   be reserved for ADB. if any of these  ports is already used, the
>   emulator will fail to start.

Is there a way to make adb work with more than 16 emulators ?

Comment: What are you trying to do by running 17 emulators? I am just curious.

Comment: I'm in the academia, running an experiment. Working on automatic test generation for Android apps.

Comment: Have you been able to come up with a fix ? I am working on something similar and can't get past the limit.

Answer (score 2):

You need to increase `ADB_LOCAL_TRANSPORT_MAX` in [adb/transport_local.cpp](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/master/adb/transport_local.cpp) to the desired value and recompile the `adb` binary.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it.

Comment: It looks like this is not the only change needed. In the bundled version of qemu with the Android sdk there is an imposed limit of 16 emulators: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/qemu/+/gingerbread-release/android/qemu-setup.c#322

Comment: @FlyingPumba I've not found this to be the case in practice: that error only appears if it can't connect - and it only won't if adb hasn't been set up to allow it.

Answer (score 1):

From v41, you can set ADB_LOCAL_TRANSPORT_MAX_PORT as an env-var without needing to recompile. This has the same effect as increasing transport_max count.

Run adb --help: my patch also added documentation for this environment variable at the bottom of the help text.