# Start more than 16 emulators

Tags: android, android-emulator, emulation

I want to start more than 16 android emulators with

- Ubuntu 18.04
- jdk8

The report error is

> It seems too many emulator instances are running on this machine. Aborting.

I know the question is similar with [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46596025/how-to-start-more-than-16-android-emulators). However, its solutions did't work.

I have tried:

- execute `export ADB_LOCAL_TRANSPORT_MAX_PORT=5999` in terminal
- add `ADB_LOCAL_TRANSPORT_MAX_PORT=5999` in `~/.bashrc`
- run the command `ADB_LOCAL_TRANSPORT_MAX_PORT=5999 emulator -avds test_x86`

However, they did't work.

I also have tried to modify the android source code and build adb as follows:

- download android source code by `repo` and execute `repo sync`
- modify the default number of emulators in `packages/modules/adb/client/transport_local.cpp`
- execute the following cmd

  - source build/envsetup.sh
  - lunch aosp_x86_64-eng
  - make -j24 adb
- replace the old adb file in android sdk with the new one

but it failed.

So what should I do to start more than 16 emulators?

Comment: Does this max amount depend on available RAM?